# US Citizen employed in India but working remotely from US

Tags: united-states, taxes, india

I am an US Citizen and also an overseas citizen of India (OCI). Last year I joined a company in India. But in September this year I had to come to US to support a family emergencies and health issues. I am currently getting paid in India but working remotely from here in India time zone. Is it legal from both US and India employment and legal perspective? 
Of course I will report this income to IRS and file taxes. India tax law says 182 days of presence in the current FY.

Please help
thanks

Comment: 182 days law applies when you don’t earn any money in India. It seems you are income is still sourced from India, hence you might need to file ITR. Have you requested your employer in India to confirm if you have any tax liabilities in India?

Comment: If your employer is Indian, they are probably already deducting tax from your payroll. It's called Tax Deduction at Source (TDS). Please check and add those details to the question.